# Open a ppt file presentation in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, powerpoint

I'm making a visula c++ project and in some point in code I'd like to open a power point file ( specifically a .ppsx file) and be able to start, move through slides and close the application.

The pseudo code goes like this:

```
presentation = new Presentation("file.ppsx");
presentation.Start();
//do something
presentation.NextSlide();
//do something else
presentation.NextSlide();
//finally close it
presentation.Finish();
```

I'd really be thankful for the code to do this and what libraries to include.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such straightforward thing available using c++ :-/ ...

Comment: I thought there'd be since it's all very microsoftish

Comment: Libreoffice is offering some APIs http://api.libreoffice.org/ , I don't know is this will fit your needs, but It's standard C++ , it's free and it works.

Comment: @tadoman _'since it's all very microsoftish'_ That **never** was a good indicator for _'straightforward solutions'_ at any time unfortunately IMHO!

Comment: If you are using _Managed_ C++ you could use the Primary Interop Assemblies (PIA) of Office for easy-interop. [An example is found here.](http://osdir.com/ml/windows.devel.dotnet.cx/2004-01/msg00072.html) Documentation is found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161225%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff759900%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is a library doing this for ppt. First, generate updated Office Type Libraries (.tlh, .tli):
Check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238972/ for current type library file names.

Import type libraries e.g. in a VS C++ project (use \):

```
    #import "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\OFFICE12\\MSO.DLL" rename("RGB", "MSRGB")
    #import "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\VBA\\VBA6\\VBE6EXT.OLB" raw_interfaces_only, rename("Reference", "ignorethis"), rename("VBE", "testVBE")
    #import "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\MSPPT.OLB" exclude("IFont", "IPicture") rename("RGB", "ignorethis"), rename("DialogBox", "ignorethis"), rename("VBE", "testVBE"), rename("ReplaceText", "EReplaceText"), rename("CopyFile","ECopyFile"), rename("FindText", "EFindText"), rename("NoPrompt", "ENoPrompt")
```

Compile. Tlh/tli files will be created in \udebug or \urelease.
Copy them to your project.

In C++, try something like this.

```
    PowerPoint::DesignPtr my_design= my_active_presentation->Designs->Load(as_bstr(template_filename), 1);
```

You will find more doc under: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint

It may not help you directly, because it's too late. But it could help others trying to solve the same problem.